# Unable to set the http defaults inside the angularjs factory

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

In my Angularjs application, I have a factory and I need to authenticate a user. I am using the `httpProvider` to set the defaults. But I am getting the error stating `$httpProvider` is not defined.

```
'use strict';
 angular.module('myApp')
.factory('authService', function ($q, $http, $rootScope, $window) {
    return {
        authenticateUser: function () {
           ........
           ........
       $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = 'application/json, text/javascript';
       $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
```

I then tried by adding the `$httpProvider` in the factory dependency

```
'use strict';
 angular.module('myApp')
.factory('authService', function ($q, $http, $rootScope, $window, httpProvider ) {
    return {
        authenticateUser: function () {
           ........
           ........
       $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = 'application/json, text/javascript';
       $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
```

This time I am getting the `Unknown provider: $httpProviderProvider <- $httpProvider <- authService`

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get service provider inside the factory.

You can use `interceptors` to add a default value to each http request.

```
angular.module('myApp').config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptorService');
});

angular.module('myApp').factory('authInterceptorService', ['$q', '$location', 'localStorageService', function ($q, $location, localStorageService) {
var authInterceptorServiceFactory = {};
var _authentication = {
    isAuth: false,
    userName: ""
};

var _request = function (config) {
    config.headers = config.headers || {};
    var authData = localStorageService.get('data');
    if (authData) {
        config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + authData;
    }

    return config;
}

authInterceptorServiceFactory.request = _request;

return authInterceptorServiceFactory;
}]);
```

Comment: I saw this in your code snippet: `$httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptorService');` What if I have many service where I need to use the `interceptors`?

Comment: One question. Where I `config` defined? I am getting `config` as `undefined`

Comment: @Pradeep, which `config` your are asking about? the `angular.module.config()` or the parameter with name `config`?

Comment: @Pradeep, our `interceptorsFactory.request()` will be fired when we make a `$http` request from angularJS. It should pass a configuration object to the `request()` method.

Comment: @Pradeep, is your `_request ()` method is fired when make a `http` request?

Comment: Got it. Thanks for letting me know this feature in Angularjs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104223/discussion-between-pradeep-and-abhilash-p-a-pullelil).

Answer (score 2):

$httpProvider is accessible only in config like

```
angular.module('myApp')
.config(function($httpProvider){
   $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
})
```

Comment: Will this config be applied for all the requests throughout the application or we need to use `interceptors` for all the `request`?

Comment: @Pradeep yes, it will apply to all requests :)